# extracting wrong value from database

Tags: java, database, int, long-integer

I am inserting a long value into the database of 10 numeric digits. (example : 9876543219). It is saving the value in the database correctly. But when I try to extract the data from the database I am getting a different number like (1286608627).

Note: if the number is less than 10 digits everything is working fine.

I am using the following code to get the data from the database:

```
int getmyNumber = ((BigDecimal) TTRefermap.get("GET_MY_NUMBER")).intValue();
```

I can see the value of getMyNumber in Database as : 9876543219 (as expected).

Comment: Hint: What is max value for `int`?

Comment: Hint 2: google for integer overflow.

Comment: @Pshemo thanks .The max value should be 2,147,483,647. So if we give the values before the max value that should work fine right??Also can you please let me know what should I use to make it work until 999999999.

Comment: Correct. Is `9,876,543,219` before that value?

Comment: If `int` can't hold your value don't use it. Use other type which can hold it like `long`, or `BigInteger` for unlimited (except memory size) value.

Comment: @Pshemo Perfect got the solution and got the concept as well. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
long getmyNumber = ((BigDecimal) TTRefermap.get("GET_MY_NUMBER")).longValue();
```

because range of integer is only `2^31-1`

or you can convert it to `BigInteger` as following:

```
BigInteger getmyNumber = ((BigDecimal) TTRefermap.get("GET_MY_NUMBER")).toBigInteger();
```